# Is there any way to join two or more tables in oracle database(or any database) without using foreign key relationship?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, create-table

Say I want to create 2 tables.
Table A has student_id, student_name, student_address and Table B has student_id, student_marks.
While creating these two tables is there any other way to establish the relationship between these 2 tables without using foreign key concept in oracle Database or any other database generally?

Comment: Foreign keys are there to ensure data consistency. They are not _needed_ to join.

Comment: While it is certainly possible (see answer by @Gordon Linoff) one is compelled to as _why_ you seem to want to avoid a FK.  Certainly there are cases where even a perfect data design leaves you needing to join on columns without a FK.  But the example you give is textbook FK situation. So why would you NOT define an FK when appropriate?  As noted by jarlh, the very _purpose_ of FK are used to ensure data consistency, not to somehow facilitate a join.

Comment: What does "establish the relationship between tables" mean, other than declaring a FK constraint? How are you stuck? At what point in what textbook? PS "Relationship" is sometimes used to mean FK constraint, although in the relational model & ER model it means "association"  in the sense of a relation/table representing an association.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join tables on any keys you like -- assuming the comparison logic is syntactically correct.  They do not have to be declared as foreign keys.

The purpose of foreign keys is to maintain data integrity.  You cannot put a `student_id` in `B` that is not in `A`.  If you don't care about that, or don't understand it, or don't need it, then there is no need to declare the foreign key relationship.

Whether or not it is declared, you can still join the tables.